# Facebook-login issue

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-social-plugins, fbconnect, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is our link for the fb or old way sign-in: http://www.greeceinsiders.com/login

Does the fb-login work to you? When I click it it redirects me to the same page.

Sometimes it works sometimes not. When a user logs in with fb we collect his vredentials sucha as email,city, name in our mysql database. Does  anybody had the same problem? Is there any good tutorial out there, that explains it step by step and is for the current fb api?

Any suggestions or feedback is welcome, thank you! Some code

FOUND IT!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the FB.login method.  This allows me to set the permissions that I want (such as email) and access the info on my server through a Facebook library like https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.  There are also good tutorials on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/:

```
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: Global.base_url + 'user/facebook_log_in/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {}
                });
            }
            else {
                // Display facebook error
            }
        }, 
    {
        scope: 'email'
    });
```